# Three finger tap lookup no longer show Wikipedia pages since upgrading to Sierra

Tags: macos

First, it showed nothing but I had to go to the dictionary and download it but now I can't lookup things that aren't in the dictionary, that would previously result in it showing me a Wikipedia page.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: The support article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352. You have to enable force click by going to **System Preferences** -> Trackpad -> Force Click and Haptic Feedback.

Comment: @EdricChan I don't have a force touch trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses Spotlight Suggestions for this functionality since El Capitan: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21573

> If you’re using OS X v10.10.3 or later and Spotlight Suggestions are enabled in Spotlight preferences, you may also see information about related music, movies, or map locations.

But Spotlight Suggestions are disabled for some reason in most countries: http://www.apple.com/macos/feature-availability/#spotlight-suggestions

Check if your country is in the Supported list. If not, you're out of luck at the moment, just as me. I couldn't find any *normal* workaround, that doesn't involve constant VPN connection. If you're OK with VPN inconvenience, cost and additional latency, you may check this solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3cln0j/how_can_you_enable_spotlight_suggestions_in_mac/

Supported countries at the time of writing:

- Australia
- Austria
- Belgium
- Canada
- France
- Germany
- Ireland
- Italy
- Japan
- Mexico
- Netherlands
- New Zealand
- Spain
- Switzerland
- UK
- USA

Answer (score 1):

This question is more than four years old, yet I did not experience the same issue until I upgraded to MacOS 11 Big Sur NOV 2020. This thread however helped me to work out an easy fix by clicking Spotlight in System Preferences and choosing both "Siri Suggestions" + "Other." Options now include an array of responses to three tap lookup such as News; Siri Suggested Web Sites; Movies; iTunes; Maps; et al. Often it displays Siri Knowledge instead of Wikipedia, but appears to scrape, or be interchangeable from Wikipedia. In any case I'm provided with deeper breadth and context then merely Dictionary and works quite well.